# Entity Framework Code First TPH Inheritance with Generic Repository

Tags: inheritance, c#-4.0, repository, ef-code-first, single-table-inheritance

I'm probably misunderstanding code-first table-per-hierarchy inheritance, but this is my set-up: I have HTMLGadgets (and other types) inheriting from Gadget, which inherits from Entity. Entity has one property, Id, so I can use it in a generic repository, à la [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

```
public abstract class Entity {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}   

public abstract class Gadget : Entity {       
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class HTMLGadget : Gadget
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
}
```

To implement TPH inheritance I have this in my context:

```
public DbSet<Gadget> Gadgets { get; set; }
```

So, I want everything to use the base Id, so everything is an Entity. But how do I get that to participate in code first inheritance? I can see the problem: if I change the context to have

```
public DbSet<Entity> Entities{ get; set; }
```

it might work, but I'd have everything (there will be more tables other than gadgets) in one hierarchy table! But I can't see how I can get my EF POCO classes to 'bottom-out' at Gadgets, yet still have Gadgets use the base Entity Id property so they can be used in the generic repository. Can anyone help?-

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to map `Entity` class. Introducing `DbSet<Entity>` will map `Entity` class. If  you are going to sore different types of Gadgets in a single table, then map the `Gadget` and other sub classes.

The properties declared in Entity` class will be used by EF to map the sub classes.